# ConfigParser removes quotes from empty values

Tags: python, python-2.7, ini, configparser

I have an INI windows file with the following format:

```
[STRINGS]
property 1 = "hello"
property 2 = ""
PROPERTY 3 = ""
```

but if I get values using ConfigParser

```
init_values= ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
init_values.optionxform = str
init_values.read(init_file)
```

and modify one of them (p.e. property 1)

```
init_values.set('STRINGS', 'property 1', '"world"')
init_values.write(configfile)
```

I get the following result:

```
[STRINGS]
property 1 = "world"
property 2 = 
PROPERTY 3 =
```

All the quotes from empty values are removed.

How can I force to use quotes even in empty values?

Answer (score 1):

```
init_values.set('STRINGS', 'property 1', '"world"')
```

If you look at what you are doing here, you are explicitly adding quotes to the value. If you were to remove the quotes around `world`, you would just get the following output:

```
[STRINGS]
property 1 = world
property 2 =
property 3 =
```

That is because INI files don’t actually use quotes to signalize string values (since every value is a string).

What may be a problem though is that the *parser* explicitly recognizes `""` as an empty string value and replaces it by the empty string, while quotes around other values are kept as they are. This is a built-in behavior of the 2.7 parser and cannot really be changed without implementing it yourself.

Note that in Python 3, this behavior was changed, so `""` is being recognized as the string `'""'`.

Comment: Thanks for the acclaration, I just go through all values and replace `''` by `'""'`

Answer (score 0):

Let's take have an INI windows file with the following format:

```
[STRINGS]
property 1 = "hello"
property 2 = ""
PROPERTY 3 = ""
```

You can do it by following way. For example:

```
import ConfigParser

filename='config'
parser=ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
parser.read([filename])
print(parser.sections())
# ['section']
for section in parser.sections():
    print(parser.options(section))
    # ['id', 'rb', 'person']
    for option in parser.options(section):
        try:
            value=parser.getint(section,option)
        except ValueError:
            value=parser.get(section,option)
        print(option,value,type(value))
print(parser.items('section'))
# [('property1', 'world'), ('property2', ''), ('property3', '')]
```

Comment: But if I use this aproach, I continue having nothing after '=' sign